# Proving the Equality if f(U and V) = f(U) and f(V)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

If $f:X \to Y$ is a function and $U$ and $V$ are subsets of $X$, then $f(U \cap V) = f(U) \cap f(V)$.

I am a little lost on this proof. I believe it to be true, but I am uncertain as to where to start. Any solutions would be appreciated. I have many similar proofs to prove and I would love a complete one to base my further proofs on.

Comment: Think about $f(x)=x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prove it, since it is false. Take a set $X$ with more than one point, take $x,x'\in X$ with $x\neq x'$ and let $f$ be a constant function. Then$$f\bigl(\{x\}\cap\{x’\}\bigr)=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset\neq f\bigl(\{x\}\bigr)\cap f\bigl(\{x'\}\bigr).$$

Actually, the assertion that you want to prove is equivalent to the assertion that $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove the equality unless $f$ is injective.

If you prove something by Double-Inclusion, then you get the equality. However, at this case you will just get the equality right if $f$ is injective.

I will do one inclusion
$$f(U  \cap V)  \subset  f(U)   \cap  f(V)$$

- Let $y \in  f(U  \cap V)$ such that $y=f(x)$.
- Since$ y \in  f(U  \cap V)$ such that $y=f(x)$, then there is $x\in U  \cap V$.
- Since $x\in U  \cap V$, then $x\in U$ **and** $x\in V$ [by the intersection Definition]

  - For $x\in U$, you get $y\in f(U)$ such that $y=f(x)$.
  - For $x\in V$, you get $y\in f(V)$ such that $y=f(x)$.
  - In a function, every element of domain has to be "linked" to at least one element of the codomain. Otherwise, it will be not a function. (Not talking about injective or surjective functions at this point).
- Therefore, since $y\in f(U)$ and $y\in f(V)$, then $y \in  f(U)  \cap  f(V)$, by the Intersection Definition again.
- Since y is an arbitrary element, then $f(U  \cap V)  \subset  f(U)   \cap  f(V)$

The other inclusion you'll only get if $f$ is injective (the reason of this has already been answered by someone).